# <IfModule prefork> in Apache 2.4 (Amazon) is not in httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, lamp, mpm-prefork

I am running an AWS EC2 instance with LAMP (apache 2.4 (amazon). I am trying to tune the prefork module but I can't find it.

I have checked the httpd.conf file and it is not in there. I have confirmed that it is running prefork mpm.

I am looking for the somthing similar to the following:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
```

```
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
# LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
```

Does anyone know where those files are located?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the prefork module is enabled ( Unless you disabled it, it's enabled by default ).

The file you're looking for is in the enabled modules directory:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf
```

Comment: I don't have an `apache2` file. I have `httpd`